# Downloading uploaded files from Amazon S3 service in a Spring MVC web app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a problem of downloading my uploaded files from amazon s3 service. I have succesfully implemented the upload section, all I need is to download these file to my local hardrive the view them later. My application is a spring mvc application.

This is my controller to call the download service

```
@Controller
public class fileController{
@Autowired S3Service s3Service;
@Autowired AwsConfig awsConfig;
@Autowired Environment env;
@Autowired DocRepository docRepo;

@RequestMapping(value="downloadDocume")
public void downloadDocument(@RequestParam("docId") Long docId
,HttpServletRequest request ,HttpServletResponse response)){
Document doc = docRepo.findOne(docId);
String docName = doc.getAsset().getName();
 String ASSET_PATH = awsConfig.getBaseUrl()+"/"+
                   awsConfig.getBucket()+"/";

    if (Objects.equals(env.getProperty("spring.profiles.active"),"prod")){
        ASSET_PATH= awsConfig.getBaseUrl()+"/"+
                awsConfig.getBucket()+"/";
    }

   String filtered = StringUtils.delete(docName, ASSET_PATH);
String mimetype = request.getSession().getServletContext().getMimeType(filtered);
    FileStream file = s3Service.getAssetByName("/Documents/", filtered);
    response.setContentType(mimetype);
    response.setContentLength((int) file.getSize());

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + docName +"\"");
    FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
 }
}
```

//This is my S3Sservice class with the download method

```
 @Service
public class S3Service{
public FileStream getAssetByName(String path , String name)
        throws FileNotFoundException{
    AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(
            new BasicAWSCredentials(awsConfig.getAccessKey(), awsConfig.getSecretKey()));
    s3.setEndpoint(awsConfig.getBaseUrl());
    s3.setS3ClientOptions(new S3ClientOptions().withPathStyleAccess(true));
    S3Object obj = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(awsConfig.getBucket(), getS3Path(path) + name));
    return new FileStream(obj.getObjectContent(), obj.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength());
}


 }
```

Comment: Where's the error exactly?

Comment: It ttrows an Amazon S3 service exception: Not Found at  S3Object obj = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(awsConfig.getBucket(), getS3Path(path) + name)); in the getAssetByName()

Comment: Thi is th stac trace   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: null)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1077)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:725)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460) @moffeltje

Comment: After you run the upload command, did you checked the file is successfully uploaded? (For example: Logging into the AWS web console)
I would print out the 'getS3Path(path) + name' part, to see what the S3 would try to access?

Comment: I have tried that and its telling me to "Please provide an object id" which I dont understand how to... Its actually my first time using amazon s3Service @AdamOcsvari. This is the result of of the 'getS3Path(path)+ name'  http://localhost:9444/s3/harambesaweb// fe0ec4b8-728d-4355-a9b5-ad9c2dbf17b2_character.png.

Comment: What is your path variable? this is a local address, you need to achieve a valid AWS S3 route. It is something like: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/......." ( notice that it contains a region, that may be different for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow.. The solution was very simple.. I just used the the html download link and passed the parameters on my jsp like this. This is i my document.jsp

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="${document.asset.name}" download="${document.asset.name}">Download Document</a>
```

I change my downloadDocument() in my controller to look like this

```
public void downloadDocument(@RequestParam("docId") Long docId
,HttpServletRequest request ,HttpServletResponse response)){
Document doc = docRepo.findOne(docId);
model.addAtribute("document" , doc);
return "document";
 }
}
```